# Why I am getting 401 error in WordPress rest API when I trying to create new post with postman?

Tags: wordpress

I am getting

> 401 Unauthorized

Headers

Response body

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like permission issue,

Comment: I am using basic json authentication plugin for authorization and i am inserting right credential in postman but found 401.

Comment: yes buddy i appreciate that you are using correct credentials but i am saying that it seem the credentials you are using does not have rights/permission to perform that action. check [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-api-cant-create-a-post/)

Comment: I am using administrator  credential which have all the permissions.

Comment: I have the same issue and I can create post in wp-admin with the user I'm using for authentication , I use JWT plugin